# Wordpress style active menu item on custom menu

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm creating a wordpress template and currently I'm working on the menu, I've made the following:

http://jsfiddle.net/skunheal/Umkyr/

There are 2 small problems I dont really know how to fix tho. Wordpress gives the currently active menu item the class .current_page_item. how can I style this?

I was thinking something like:

Normal menu item:

```
ul.dropdown a {
text-decoration : none;
font-family : verdana;
color : #3f89d2;
display : inline-block;
background : #FFF;
padding : 8px 15px 0 15px;
box-shadow : 0 0 10px #CCC inset;
width : auto;
height : 25px;
}
```

Active menu item:

```
.current_page_item a {
background : #096;

}
```

but it doesnt seems to work.
Anyone know why?

Thanx in advance,
Merijn

Comment: I can't see anything wrong -  which class are you trying to use for your active menu in your fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write it like this

```
 li.current_page_item a {
    color:#096
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Umkyr/5/)**

Comment: 1 more fast question. the width of the drop down is 200px right now. Instead of that I want to make it auto scale to the largest item. so I tried width:auto. that gives me the following result. do you know why? http://jsfiddle.net/skunheal/Umkyr/7/